# Getting most recent record through another related table

Tags: mysql

How would I create a MySQL command to get the most recent categories that have had a post favorited?

I am attempting to join the tables and group them, but am unsure how to limit the results to a maximum number of categories.

So to give a simple example of what I'm trying to do:

```
Users (id)
Favorites (id, last_updated, post_id, user_id)
Posts (id, title, category_id)
Categories (id, name)
```

And then for sql:

```
SELECT favorites.*, posts.category_id
FROM favorites
INNER JOIN posts ON favorites.user_id = 1 AND favorites.post_id = posts.id
INNER JOIN categories ON posts.category_id = categories.id
GROUP BY categories.id, favorites.id
ORDER BY favorites.last_updated DESC
```

Obviously, this statement is not working as intended, as it returns many results for each category, instead of one for each category - the most recent.

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't `GROUP BY` a field not present in `SELECT`.

Here is a solution assuming that you want this only for user_id = 1:

```
SELECT c.id, MAX(f.last_updated)
FROM favorites f
INNER JOIN posts p ON (f.user_id = 1 AND f.post_id = p.id)
INNER JOIN categories c ON (p.category_id = c.id)
GROUP BY c.id
ORDER BY MAX(f.last_updated) DESC
```

With this you get the IDs of the desired categories. You can join the result with categories again to get the rest of the columns.